# C# - Very slow string variable calculation

Tags: c#, string, performance

I have over 27,000,000 string variable in the array. When I add a string to another one speed is greatly reduced. my code is:

```
 //public string[] part2 = { .....
 string Str1;
 string Str0;
 Parallel.ForEach(index_choose, x =>
         {
             Str1 += part1[x];
             Str0 += part2[x];

            //progressBar1.PerformStep();
            //label1.Text = progressBar1.Value.ToString();
            //Application.DoEvents();
        });
string total = Str1 + Str0;
```

Run this code on a powerful CPU takes More than 20 hours!

Comment: Were you not expecting 27 million string operations to take a long time?

Comment: This is precisely what `StringBuilder` is for. Although note that if you're doing everything in parallel, the results will be non-deterministic anyway. You probably want to build strings in each partition, and combine them later on. Or just start without using `Parallel.ForEach`...

Comment: Did you run this code with the label1.Text uncommented?

Comment: This is because of your `array` size. You should try splitting this into several `arrays`.

Comment: @DaisyShipton `StringBuilder` is not at all thread safe. At the very least you will have data loss, but it may also throw exceptions. If you want to use `StringBuilder`, it has to be done on a single thread.

Comment: @RonBeyer: There's data loss in the current code as well, given that `Str1 += part[x]` could be executed on multiple threads at once. Hence the rest of my comment.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Right, but it is *precisely **not** what `StringBulder` is for* (in the OP's context). It isn't that it is non-deterministic, to use `StringBuilder` it must be single threaded or use one `StringBuilder` per thread.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Fair about it being more than non-deterministic - I'd say that `StringBuilder` *is* for "building strings quickly" but needs to then be used more carefully than the OP is handling their data at the moment at all.

Comment: Just as a reference, using a non-parallel approach I can concatenate 27 million strings of varying lengths (1-10 characters) resulting in a 255 million character string in less than 6 seconds using `StringBuilder`, in debug mode. The parallel use of StringBuilder was 3.4 seconds, but resulted in ~79% of the data being lost (54 million characters with same input in the result). Code: https://pastebin.com/LNGnVgAw

Comment: Yup - I'd definitely go for "single thread" before embracing the complexity of per-partition concatenation etc.

Answer (score 3):

I will recommend to use StringBuilder - like in the following example

```
StringBuilder str0 = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder();
Parallel.ForEach(index_choose, x =>
         {
             Str1.Append(part1[x]);
             Str0.Append(part2[x]);

        //progressBar1.PerformStep();
        //label1.Text = progressBar1.Value.ToString();
        //Application.DoEvents();
    });
string total = Str1.Append(Str0).ToString();
```

Comment: This is better, however `StringBuilder.Append` (and most other string builder methods) is not thread safe. This may result in a loss of data.

Comment: yes.. but also string concatenation is not thread safe. First step is to use stringbuilder and check the performance. If it's ok maybe he can remove parallel operation or add a lock mechanism.

Comment: Of course it isn't, but don't trade one bad habit for another.